# Get value of input, but strip html syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically generated inputs off of a DB table, that lists multiple 'options'. I have a script that takes the entire list of options, then splits them based on a character of `|`. After I split them, they are left as `span divs` which i then apply to inputs dynamically.

**One of these inputs looks like this:**

```
<input class="filterable-content" type="checkbox" name="topics" value="<span>Account</span>" id="group3-<span>Account</span>">
```

I am updating the url on click of these checkboxes, but since I am getting value it is bringing this whole value `<span>Account</span>`. Is there anyway to drop the `<span></span>` of the value when it appends to my url?

**Here is how I am getting values:**

```
$(".filterable-content").on("change", function() {
        var hash = $(".filterable-content:checked").map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).toArray();
        hash = hash.join("&");
        window.location.hash = 'query=' + hash;
    });
```

This is how the url should look:
`www.website.com/query=account&profile`.

This is what I am getting currently:
`www.website.com/query=<span>Account</span>&<span>Profile</span>`.

Any idea what I could do for this? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the text inside the span tag.

```js
$(".filterable-content").on("change", function() {
    var hash = $(".filterable-content:checked").map(function() {
        return $(this.value).text();
    }).toArray();
    hash = hash.join("&");
    console.log(hash);
    window.location.hash = 'query=' + hash;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="filterable-content" type="checkbox" name="topics" value="<span>Account</span>" id="group3-<span>Account</span>">
<input class="filterable-content" type="checkbox" name="topics" value="<span>Profile</span>" id="group3-<span>Account</span>">
```

Comment: Ah, I was messing up the value. Beautifully done, thank you!